# Text field doesn't change in gallery android

Tags: android, gridview

I have gridview which load few images thumbnails. When I click on some image is opened in new activity full image. Now I trying to add some description about the image. When activity is loaded the info for this image is loaded also. So far so good..

The problem comes when I click on button next which load next image(full image without to back on the gridview with thumbnails) the description doesn't update and change for the next image. Is just same description for every image.
Here I download `thumb`, `full_image` and `description`,

```
String url = "http://myhost/get.php?id=" + my_id;

        JSONArray data;
        try {
            resultServer = getJSONUrl(url);
            data = new JSONArray(resultServer);

            MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            HashMap<String, Object> map;

            for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("id", (String)c.getString("id"));
                map.put("description", (String)c.getString("description"));

                // Thumbnail Get ImageBitmap To Bitmap
                map.put("ImagePathThum", (String)c.getString("image"));
                map.put("ImageThumBitmap", (Bitmap)loadBitmap(c.getString("image")));

                // Full (for View Full)
                map.put("ImagePathFull", (String)c.getString("image_big"));

                MyArrList.add(map);
            }
```

Then this is the gridView() which display thumbs

```
    public void ShowAllContent()
{
    // gridView1
    final GridView gridV = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1); 
    gridV.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(act1.this,MyArrList));

    // OnClick
    gridV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
            String Position = String.valueOf(position);

            Intent newActivity = new Intent(act1.this,act2.class);
            newActivity.putExtra("Position", Position);
            newActivity.putExtra("resultServer", resultServer);
            newActivity.putExtra("description", MyArrList.get(position).get("description").toString());
            startActivity(newActivity);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Then In act2

```
TextView txtView;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.information);        

    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    Intent intent= getIntent();
    curPosition = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("Position")); 
    resultServer = String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("resultServer")); 
    textDescription = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(textDescription+"");

    try {
        MyArrList = ConvertJSONtoArrayList(resultServer);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("ArrayList Size",String.valueOf(MyArrList.size()));

    // Show Image Full
    new DownloadFullPhotoFileAsync().execute();

    // Button Back
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            curPosition = curPosition - 1;
            new DownloadFullPhotoFileAsync().execute();
        }
    });

    // Button Next
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            curPosition = curPosition + 1;
            new DownloadFullPhotoFileAsync().execute();
        }
    });
   }
// Show Image Full
public void ShowImageFull(String imageName, Bitmap imgFull)
{

    // Prepare Button (Back)
    if(curPosition <= 0)
    {
        back.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
    {
        back.setEnabled(true);
    }

    // Prepare Button (Next)
    Log.d("curPosition",String.valueOf(curPosition));
    Log.d("MyArrList.size",String.valueOf(MyArrList.size()));
    if(curPosition >= MyArrList.size() - 1)
    {
        next.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
    {
        next.setEnabled(true);
    }

     ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);    
     try
     {
        image.setImageBitmap(imgFull);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         // When Error
        image.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
     }
     // Show Toast
    Toast.makeText(act2.this,imageName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> ConvertJSONtoArrayList(String json) throws JSONException
{

    JSONArray data = new JSONArray(resultServer);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map;

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("ImageName", (String)c.getString("name"));
        map.put("ImagePathThum", (String)c.getString("image"));
        map.put("ImagePathFull", (String)c.getString("image_big"));
        map.put("description", (String)c.getString("description"));

        arr.add(map);
    }       
    return arr;     
}           
}
public class DownloadFullPhotoFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    String strImageName = "";
    String ImageFullPhoto = "";     
    Bitmap ImageFullBitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        strImageName = MyArrList.get(curPosition).get("ImageName").toString();
        ImageFullPhoto = MyArrList.get(curPosition).get("ImagePathFull").toString();
        ImageFullBitmap = (Bitmap)loadBitmap(ImageFullPhoto);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for long source code but I don't know which part exactly is needed.

I've tried to add in `DownloadFullPhotoFileAsync`

```
 textDescription = MyArrList.get(curPosition).get("description").toString();
```

so when is loaded `new DownloadFullPhotoFileAsync().execute();` in button next to load also this but I guess this is wrong since it doesn't work.

Comment: maybe You should try txtView.setText(textDescription+"") instead of  ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(textDescription+"");

Comment: Still description doesn't change with the description of next image

Comment: If I put `description` in `strImageName = MyArrList.get(curPosition).get("description").toString();` which display Toast it is show correct description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't setText in DoInBackground() function in Async Task, but you can do a setText of your description on PostExecute() which is a function of AsyncTask.

So i think you should try to set your description in PostExecute function in your Asynctask.

take a look at : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

I hope this help,
Cheers !

Comment: Yes, It's helped me. I've added `onPostExecute` and now the text is updated. Thank's!